# How to change a password for a User from API

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to prepare an endpoint in DRF which will allow to change a Users password. So I read this post:
[How to update user password in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845051/how-to-update-user-password-in-django-rest-framework)

But, to be honest even after read that article and implemented code from that article in my App It still doesn't work. Im a newbie in Django and Python and I dont understant what I do wrong. Can you help me in understanding what I do wrong ?

Here below is the code I implemented:

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    """
    Serializer for password change endpoint.
    """
    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

api.py

```py
# Password Change API
class ChangePasswordAPI(generics.UpdateAPIView):
        """
        An endpoint for changing password.
        """
        serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
        model = User
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def get_object(self, queryset=None):
            obj = self.request.user
            return obj

        def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                # Check old password
                if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
                    return Response({"old_password": ["Wrong password."]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                # set_password also hashes the password that the user will get
                self.object.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
                self.object.save()
                return Response("Success.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from .api import ChangePasswordAPI
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^auth/password-change/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', ChangePasswordAPI.as_view()), 
]
```

So now I send the PUT on http://localhost:8000/auth/change-password/
with following body:

```
{
    "old_password": "password1",
    "new_password": "password2"
}
```

and I get this message:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is tied to the URL pattern `auth/password-change/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)` yet you are requesting `auth/change-password`. The request should match the URL pattern.

Comment: yeap:-). I noticed that a minute ago. Sorry, and thank you for fast response. Now everything is OK