# Django: DRF custom password change view and serializer not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, change-password

I have defined a serializer class and a view class to perform password change. As usual, user needs to enter old password, then the new password for two times to confirm. I am using `AbstractBaseUser` to implement a custom user. I defined the `old_password_validator` and `new_password_validator` with suggestions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845051/how-to-update-user-password-in-django-rest-framework), though I don't know how to make it work.

I am using djangorestframework_simplejwt for all sorts of authentication.

My serializer class:

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    re_new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)

        if not validated_data['new_password']:
              raise serializers.ValidationError({'new_password': 'not found'})

        if not validated_data['old_password']:
              raise serializers.ValidationError({'old_password': 'not found'})

        if not instance.check_password(validated_data['old_password']):
              raise serializers.ValidationError({'old_password': 'wrong password'})

        if validated_data['new_password'] != validated_data['re_new_password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'passwords': 'passwords do not match'})

        if validated_data['new_password'] == validated_data['re_new_password'] and instance.check_password(validated_data['old_password']):
            instance.set_password(validated_data['new_password'])
            instance.save()
            return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['old_password', 'new_password','re_new_password']
```

I defined my view class like this:

```
class ChangePasswordView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ChangePasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I entered the values, headers and ran in postman I got this error:

Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ChangePasswordSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

I can't make anything out of this error statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass instance argument for ChangePasswordSerializer:

`serializer = ChangePasswordSerializer(instance=self.request.user, data=request.data)`

When you don't pass instance argument, serializer runs create() method when you call save()  otherwise (when instance arg provided) update() is called.