# How to implement password change in Django Rest Framework without repeating code (DRY principle)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django app that already has a web interface for changing passwords. It uses `django.contrib.auth` functions and `django.views.generic.UpdateView`. Here is the code:

```
class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    input_value = 'update password'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            try:
                request.user.auth_token.delete()  # Important!
            except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
                pass
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'input_value': self.input_value})
```

The above code works fine in the web interface. Now I want to implement REST API for changing passwords. I know that I can create `APIView`/`viewset` and `serializer` to do that (like the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38845051/2548628) question), but it will violate [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. What is the best way to implement the REST API interface for that given that there is already a fully-functional web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encapsulated the common part of changing the password in a function called `update_user_after_password_change` so that it can be used in both `view` and `viewset`. Then I have ended up using the following code structure.

### In views.py:

```
class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin,
                         generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    input_value = 'update password'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_user_after_password_change(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'input_value': self.input_value})


class PasswordChangeViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                            viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = serializers.PasswordChangeSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            old_password = serializer.data.get('old_password')
            if not user.check_password(old_password):
                return Response({'old_password': ['Wrong password.']},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            user.set_password(serializer.data.get('new_password'))
            user.save()
            update_user_after_password_change(request, user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def update_user_after_password_change(request, user):
    update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
    if hasattr(user, 'auth_token'):
        user.auth_token.delete()
```

### In serializers.py:

```
class PasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_new_password(self, value):
        validate_password(value)
        return value
```

There might be a better way by using [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/) but I do not know how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the Django rest framework for API and standard Django web views are a little bit different.
I suggest you create different endpoints for those.